# asset files not loading in on Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I am currently trying to help my friend with his Shopify store and I just started to learn Liquid, we want to load in a javascript file and an hmtl file but when we load the assets in and preview the website, nothing shows up except for a link.

Here is my code of the `three-html.liquid` file.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
```

This is the head section.

This is the body section.

```
<body>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script>
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };

        animate();
    </script>
</body>
```

And then obviously the rest of the html tags.

Now when I do `{% render 'three-html' %}` in the `theme.liquid` file and when I preview the store this is all I get .

[image: A blank screen]

We just wanna figure out how to get these files to visually display on the screen.
This is the outcome we want. The spinning cube.

[image: Spinning cube]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

short response:

- set both scripts on Assets directory, `three.js` and `custom.js`
- if you need this scripts on the entire site call them on the layout file `theme.liquid` if you need it only on a page or on some specific page, call the files on a template file.
- to call your scripts use [filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/url-filters) you have two options:
  `{{ 'three.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}` url filter plus html filter it render:

```
    <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/something_long/assets/three.js.js?hash" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but if you like to use some extra options like defer you should use a normal script tag plus an url filter :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'custom.js | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
```

Long response:

You mix some concepts, you should know the difference between [the files on the different folders off a shopify theme](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-files).

directories:

- **assets**: here go the "static" files from the site like images, fonts, css and script files, a nice function you can end the css and js files with `.liquid` and use liquid variables, it will be server rendered. to call assets you should use the [asset_url filter](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/url-filters#asset_url)
- **layout**: this liquid files are the boxes containing the base of the page, like base html structure, metas, global css and script calls. It's normal call here header and footer section too, you can create multiple layouts and use it o different pages of the site.
  IMPORTANT: you shouldn't use head and body tags anywhere else.
  The base structure of layout files:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ shop.locale }}">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="{{ 'style.css.liquid | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
        {%- if page_description -%}
          <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}">
        {%- endif -%}
      </head>
      <body>
        {% section 'header' %}
        <main role="main">
          {{ content_for_layout }}
        </main>
        {% section 'footer' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'myScript.js | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

- **Sections**: they are reusable modules of content that can be customized and re-ordered by users of the theme. Sections are very especial, because here you can set customizable parts than can be update on shopify admin, [more info here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-theme-editor).
- **Snippets**: they're reusable bits of code, it can be used anywhere and call by `render` you can even pass variables for extra customization.
- **Templates**: they manage the different site's pages, (article, product, index, page, etc) you can create an different version adding an alternate template. Here you can choose witch layout file you use. the default layout is `theme.liquid`.
  to use an alternative layout your file should start with this line

```
{%- layout 'yourOtherLayout' -%}
```

you don't need to add .liquid at the end, use just the layout name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `snippet` and add the content of `HTML` file content to that snippet and use `render` to load it into `theme.liquid`

```
{% render 'three-html' %}
```

Read more about `snippets` [Link](https://www.shopify.in/partners/blog/88186566-tips-for-using-snippets-in-your-shopify-theme) and `render`
[Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/theme-tags#render)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay I did that, and it's still not working. Should I change the link from "three.js" to "assets/three.js" inside of the snippet file and the html file in the assets folder? @Onkar

Comment: Snippets are comes under snippets into the theme and JS file is under assets into Shopify theme and you are using the correct syntax to include a JS file so no need to change it.

Comment: yeah I see that, but still no luck. The preview expands the section likes it gonna show the cube but ends up closing back to a blank smaller section. @Onkar

Comment: Without checking the webpage, I am not able to say anything, what is the actual cause of not working.

Comment: I'll add the code file and the preview when I run it hold on @Onkar

Comment: I think you do not need to add the HTML file, it just contains head and basic structure and script auto add the three js to the body of the page after init.

Comment: So are you saying just directly put the three.js code in the theme.liquid file and remove the {% render .... %} ? @Onkar

Comment: yes, you just include the JS and JS code to the theme.liquid file.

Answer (score -1):

It's all good 3dgifmaker.com did the job. Thanks anyways.